# MySQL MyISAM indexing a text column

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a slow performing query on my table. It has a where clause such as:

```
where supplier= 'Microsoft'
```

The column type is *text*. In phpmyadmin I looked to see if I could add an index to the table but the option is disabled. Does this mean that you can not index a text column? Does this mean that every update query like this is performing a full table scan?

Would then the best thing to do is separate the column into it's own table and place an ID in the current table then place an index on that? Would this potentially speed up the query?

Comment: You're usage profile on SE is quite exceptional: low votes but huge numbers of views.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a prefix length to the index. Have a look at [Column Indexes docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-indexes.html)

The following creates an index on the first 50 bytes of supplier field:

```
mysql> create index supplier_ix on t(supplier(50));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

But maybe you should rethink the datatype of supplier? Judging from the name, it doesn't sound like a typical text field...

Comment: Would this prevent a full table scan from occurring?

Comment: If I say yes, would you still rethink your choice of data type? :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do a check on

```
select max(length(supplier)) from the_table;
```

If the length is less than 255, you can (and you should) convert it to varchar(255) and built an index on it

Choosing a right data type is more important.

If the length is long, built an index on limited length will help.

Comment: This returns me 14. In "general" will a varchar column perform better than a text column (even if the text column is indexed?).

Comment: In general it will. And you can use VARCHAR for up to 65536 characters.

Comment: ... 65536 characters across all columns. It means if you have two columns each can be approx 32765 bytes long. (Note that UTF uses 3 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

Did I understand you right? It's a TEXT column? As in the type that corresponds to BLOB? Might I advise considering a VARCHAR for this column?

Comment: Can you still do full text search on a varchar column?

Comment: Yes you can. The question is, whether you should use full text search for a column that supposedly contains a supplier's name. The `where supplier= 'Microsoft'` condition does not use full text index anyway.